# Next-auth - rotating refresh tokens with multiple rerenders

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I did a token refresh rotation in nextjs (pages dir) + next-auth along with CredentialsProvider. I have such a problem that when I use useSession in the code or getSession, when I refresh the application or the first entry, the application rerender from 3-6x ( depending on the amount of use of hooks ). The problem is when the user's session expires and he makes a request for refresh token, the request goes 3-6x.... So it gets sent several times the same token and becomes invalid.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Using next-auth I can't use getSession and useSession? I need them for interceptors or using user data during login...

searching in documentation and on the Internet. Nothing resulted

Comment: Hey, did you have try ```module.exports = { reactStrictMode: false }```?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I will remove all my "useSession" and "getSession" which i need for example for protected routes wrapper in SSR... + with disabled strictMode then everything works fine. 

But I think it is incorrect to disable strict mode and not use hooks :/